# Can I define multiple itemRenderers in a Flex / Actionscript list

Tags: apache-flex, list, actionscript, user-interface

Basically I want to override some function in the flex/actionscript list class which creates a new ItemRenderer and passes it the required data ready to be displayed.  I need to do this because I wish to show a different renderer based on the type of data being displayed.  Is there such a function?

I don't really want to pass the list a single itemRenderer which calls its addChild function depending on the type of data it has - It just doesn't seem right...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override public method `createItemRenderer(data:Object):IListItemRenderer` of `ListBase` class (and `List`, which extends `ListBase`)

Comment: OMG!  How did I not see that function!  I must be going blind.  Thanks for your help dude :)